# get error of twisted setup when install Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to install Scrapy but the system showed me the error notification like the below images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWYH6.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOVAJ.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6qQv.jpg

I also tried to use pip install twisted but it also failed too

Any solution for this problem, pls help me
Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with: What python version you are using? Are the command `pip install scrapy` done in admin mode?

Comment: I guess you are using python 3.7. You should try using other stable versions of Python

Comment: absolutely right. it's 3.7.3

Comment: any suggest of python version to make it more stable. Thanks

Comment: Better go with Python 3.5.0 I am using that. If you want then I will add this as answer to your post Even the version download reference

Comment: Are you there?Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can try Python 3.5.0. : https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/
The scrapy might have issues with the Python 3.7.x, as it is latest one and might show some complications.

Comment: thank you. Should I uninstall my current version or just install this version?

Comment: You can have both versions. But need to change the Environment variables. Also, you can uninstall the current version and try installing the new one. In that case you need not have to worry about the environment variables.